# Solr Order result without sort

Tags: search, solr, search-engine

I m new to solr.

I have a schema for **product** with 3 fields

> price, name, size.

Field `size` has 3 values [type="text_general"]

> small, medium, large

I want to show results in a particular order :

User has an option to mention its size.

If user selects **small** as the size the ordering should be

> first show all small products followed by medium and large.

If user selects **medium** as the size the ordering should be

> first show all medium products followed by small and large.

If user selects **large** as the size the ordering should be

> first show all large products followed by medium and small.

How can I achieve this?

I tried **grouping result** but had no success.

`http://localhost:8983/solr/product/select?start=0&row=10&q=*:*&group=true&group.field=size&group.format=simple&group.limit=100000&sort=size desc`

I think sort is not the way to achieve this ordering.
Is there any other feature in SOLR to do this?

Comment: what is the field type of the field size?

Comment: also sort order is missing desc or asc

Comment: By luck (small sorts after medium which sorts after large) you should be able to sort your documents as you want by just using `sort=size desc`. However, when you start introducing XL and XS and similar sizes, this will break. Instead, index a separate sort value that represents the sort order, 10 for xxs, 20 for xs, 30 for s, 40 for m, 50 for l, 60 for xl, 70 for xxl, etc.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I have edited the question to give more clarity. Please do have a Look and help me out.